# Converting types for sorting : any runtime cost?

Tags: sorting, go, casting

I'm just getting to grips with Go (started two days ago and wrote less than 1000 lines), and I'm still wondering about some idioms.

I needed to sort a slice of strings by descending length. I did like so :

```
func ... {
    ... do business ...

    sort.Sort(stringsLongestFirst(severalThousandStrings))

    ... carry on and be happy, because it works ...
}

type stringsLongestFirst []string

func (b stringsLongestFirst) Len() int           { return len(b) }
func (b stringsLongestFirst) Less(i, j int) bool { return len(b[i]) > len(b[j]) }
func (b stringsLongestFirst) Swap(i, j int)      { b[j], b[i] = b[i], b[j] }
```

First of all I wonder if this is the most idiomatic way to do it.

And then, most of all, I wonder about what happens under the hood when I write `stringsLongestFirst(severalThousandStrings)`. Does the string slice somehow get smartly reinterpreted as a `stringsLongestFirst` type, or do I have to count with some copying overhead ?

*(edited : removed the excerpt from the specification, that was ill-suited to the case at hand)*

Comment: Nothing here is special to strings. (I think those parts of the spec are about conversions involving `[]rune` and `[]byte`.) It's pulling `len` each time `Less` is called. That's fast because [strings are (pointer, length) pairs](http://research.swtch.com/godata)--there would likely be no gain if you tried to cache the lengths separately.

Comment: So if I follow well, the casting from plain []string to a []string in disguise dressed up with a sort.Interface does not actually change anything about the memory representation, is that right ?

Comment: Exactly. If you're curious, the [interface value](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces) is generally a pointer to type information and a second pointer to the underlying object. Wouldn't sweat the speed of this too much--sorting several thousand strings by length is probably milliseconds of CPU time.

Comment: Indeed, no sweat on this one. But since I'm just teaching my self, that was an occasion to raise the topic. Thanks a lot 222 !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types you are converting is neither a numeric type or a string: `[]string` and `stringsLongestFirst` are slice types.

So the conversion should incur no more overhead than copying the slice header (which is 12 or 24 bytes, depending on the word size), which would happen anyway when packing it as an `interface{}` variable in order to call `Sort`.  The backing array is not copied, which is why `severalThousandStrings` appears to be sorted after the call.

Comment: That makes sense, and helps me build a model. Thanks !